# Value in django html does not change

Tags: html, django-templates

I am trying to show the total, everything else works just fine, but the value only changes inside the for, so total sums just fine inside, but as soon as it is out of the for it goes back to 0, how can i fix that?

```
<div class="ticket">
    <h1>Detalle de Venta</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Tamaño</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% with total=0 %}
            {% load custom_tags %}
            {% for detalle_venta in detalle_ventas %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ detalle_venta.producto.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ detalle_venta.producto.get_tamanio_display }}</td>
                <td>{{ detalle_venta.cantidad }}</td>
                <td>{{ detalle_venta.subtotal }}</td>
                
            
            {% sum_variable total detalle_venta.subtotal as total %}
            <td>{{total}}</td>
        </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endwith %}
            
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr class="total-row">
                <td colspan="3">Total</td>
                <td>{{ total }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

I tried updating the variable into another, and changing where i update said variable, but it still just shows 0, and i have viewed if inside the for the value for total changes and it does, only outside the for it does not